# EF6 Linq Query - How to make a query when two Foreign Key Constraints are in place

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

For the most part EF seems to handle itself quite well, using the following query in linq, I am able to get all the related table data using FK's without having to specify the one to many relationship.

```
                                 join cp in db.ClinicalPATs on s.ClinicalAssetID equals cp.ClinicalAssetID into AP
                                    from subpat in AP.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    orderby s.ClinicalAssetID descending


                                    select new ClinicalASSPATVM
                                    {
                                        ClinicalAssetID = s.ClinicalAssetID,
                                        ProductName = s.ProductName,
                                        ModelName = s.ModelName,
                                        SupplierName = s.SupplierName,
                                        ManufacturerName = s.ManufacturerName,
                                        SerialNo = s.SerialNo,
                                        PurchaseDate = s.PurchaseDate,
                                        PoNo = s.PoNo,
                                        Costing = s.Costing,
                                        TeamName = s.TeamName,
                                        StaffName = s.StaffName,
                                        InspectionDocumnets = subpat.InspectionDocumnets ?? String.Empty,
                                        InspectionOutcomeResult = subpat.InspectionOutcomeResult

                                    });
```

the above code pulls in the relationship data from the ViewModel.

```
     public Product ProductName { get; set; }
        public InspectionOutcome InspectionOutcomeResult { get; set; }
        public Model ModelName { get; set; }
        public BudgetCode Code { get; set; }
        public AssetType AssetTypeName { get; set; }
        public Manufacturer ManufacturerName { get; set; }
        public Staff StaffName { get; set; }
        public Team TeamName { get; set; }
        public Supplier SupplierName { get; set; }
```

I have a new problem which I have created for myself. I wanted to add an ID Field to the `Models` entity this helps me filter the data in a drop down list. I called the Field Name: `ModelAssetAsignmentID` And when someone adds a new `ModelName` from the Clinical Controller the `ModelAssetAsignmentID` gets a value of two.

So when i added the Field `ModelAssetAsignmentID` to the model "Models" i created a second FK as such:
[image: Diagram1]

My Original Linq Query is now broken, it no longer displays the modelname. I'm guessing this is due to the two FK Constraints.

Making the following change did not work, the InnerException is null.

```
var ClinicalASSPATVM = (from s in db.ClinicalAssets
                                    where (s.ModelAssetAssignmentID.Equals(2))
                                    join cp in db.ClinicalPATs on s.ClinicalAssetID equals cp.ClinicalAssetID into AP
                                    from subpat in AP.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    orderby s.ClinicalAssetID descending
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove the second foreign key constraint `ModelAssetAssignmentID` and use a viewmodel to create a value in the ModelAssetAssignmentID, thus you then do not need to modify the linq query's.